# "to be" after the verb "need"

Tags: verbs

1. I **need** you **to be** here right now.
2. I **need** you here right now.

Can we remove "to be" appearing after the verb "need" in this way?

Are the following correct?

To a waiter in a restaurant:

3. Excuse me, I **need** some sauce in it.
4. Excuse me, I **need** some sauce **to be** in it.

Comment: The fourth sentence sounds weird to me.

Comment: People usually use the third sentence. It is expresses the message properly.

Answer (score 1):

> I **need** you **to be** here, right now.

This sentence expresses that the person (I) is expecting the person (you) to be present right then and there, in front of them.

> I **need** you here, right now.

This sentence is suggesting the fact that the person (I) is commanding or asking the person (you) to go there immediately. This sentence is more often used in one's workplace and can be most commonly heard in the mouth of the bosses, when they need to get their work done.

However, both the sentences can be used under other circumstances like plea (when someone is asking for something more emotionally and in an urgent manner), etc. Not necessarily always used in imperative sentences.

> Excuse me, I **need** some sauce in it.

This sentence suggests that you are asking the waiter to pour some sauce in your food. (See not always imperative.)

> Excuse me, I **need** some sauce **to be** in it.

This sentence is very absurd. I, for one, have never heard someone saying this. It is coming out more rude also if you stress on the words in the sentence. More like you are accusing the waiter, "why is there no sauce in my food?"

**To be** in these sentences are infinitives acting like adverbs. They modify the nouns or pronouns which they follow.

Answer (score 0):

The examples given might not be the best ones to illustrate the question; at a minimum, they are a small subset of that question. You can have:

> I need to be in Miami tomorrow.

but not

> I need in Miami tomorrow

But even with the 2nd set of examples in the question, the "in it" is artificial. Much better is

> Excuse me, I need some sauce

or, if you are complaining about something that can't be fixed by adding sauce now, you could try:

> Excuse me, but this dish should have sauce in it.